# Share session between phpBB and a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, phpbb

This might be a nonsensical question, but I have this task to create a rails app that shares session information, specifically login/authorization info, with an installation of a phpBB that some other person has customized to be more than just a BB.

Basically I need to rely on the user's phpBB login to authorize access to the rails app. I really don't want to have the user maintain two logins to use this conceptual single app.

I read a lot of documentation on phpBB and didn't find anything like exposed services or an API, but I'm hoping I just missed something obvious.

I've been considering adding a method to expose some hash or something to link the two applications rather than try to squeeze possibly different implementations of session.

Quick context, this work needs to be done fast and cleanly and I've never developed in php and rails is super fast so I am investigating the idea of integrating the two sides.

I might be off in the weeds, so don't be afraid to say so :)
thanks!

Comment: Just write a warden extension you can use in devise that checks the cookies from phpBB - but without any documentation on that part, it will be hell :-/.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked phpbb-auth?

https://github.com/mattfawcett/phpbb-auth